# How to exclude specific elements from being observed

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Consider a web page containing multiple elements. Defining a `MutationObserver` on the `body` will trigger the callback for every change in the DOM.

In the following example:

```
<body>
  <div>[some content...]</div>
  <div>[some content...]</div>
  <div id='special'>[]</div>

  <script>
    function onMutation(objects, instance) { ... }

    const body = document.querySelectorAll("body")[0];
    const special = document.getElementById("special");
    //MutationObserverInit options
    const moi = { childList: true, attributes: true, subtree: true };
    //create a new mutation observer
    const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
    //start observing
    mo.observe(body, moi);
  </script>
</body>
```

the `onMutation` function will be called even when the `#special` element is changed. However, in specific situations, e.g. lots of dynamic content which changes frequently and a browser not known for its speed, observing the `#special` element can have a serious impact on the performance. Regardless of the reason to do so, there might be a requirement to ignore the specific mutations of a particular element.

How could one (efficiently) "exclude" a specific element (or more) from the list of observed nodes? In the example above, all the elements in the page must be observed, except the `#special` element. It is possible to overwrite the behaviour for a specific element by calling the `observe` function on the same element with different options, but this approach does not work when calling `observe` on a child element (`#special`) of an element on which the observation has already been specified (`body`).

I currently see the following methods, each with their own set of problems/downsides:

- *select all the elements in the page except the `#special` one and observe them individually* => impractical when there are many other elements in the page and/or the layout structure is complex (element hierarchies) resulting in complicated selectors
- *filter the elements inside the callback* => although one can check inside the callback if the logic should be executed or not, the callback is still being called on (potentially many) unwanted elements.

Comment: Why do you need to observe all the DOM tree in the first hand? Can't you find a better way than using MutationObserver all together? (otherwise, I don't know a way to filter subtree elements from observation, except in the callback)

Comment: using the attributeFilter argument to ignore `style` would likely help a lot on jquery-heavy sites

Comment: @Kaiido I tried to keep the problem/question as general as possible, as I think it's a legitimate use case to try to exclude certain areas from being observed. In _my particular use case_, the answer is *3rd party* libraries 
 -- one defines the observer on the `body`, the other creates a Gantt with thousands of elements being constantly added and removed. I'm currently searching for the least disruptive way of making the Gantt usable again, without having to "adapt" other modules (which would be required if the MutationObserver would not be started, creating other issues...).

Comment: Yes it's a fair question, it's just that in general the use of MutationObserver can be avoided.

Comment: You are right. I do believe that observing the entire `body` is a performance mistake and disabling this functionality in the code is being consider... Still, it would be nice to find out if there are any alternatives...

Comment: You can temporarily disconnect the observer, update #special, start the observer. See also [Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM](//stackoverflow.com/a/39332340)